# (AWS) What happens to a python script without enough CPU?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

My small AWS EC2 instance runs a two python scripts, one to receive JSON messages as a web-socket(~2msg/ms) and write to csv file, and one to compress and upload the csvs. After testing, the data(~2.4gb/day) recorded by the EC2 instance is sparser than if recorded on my own computer(~5GB). Monitoring shows the EC2 instance consumed all CPU credits and is operating on baseline power. My question is, does the instance drop messages because it cannot write them fast enough?

Thank you to anyone that can provide any insight!

Comment: In general on AWS, if you're running out of CPU credits you should change instance types.  I'd recommend using a c5.large to process that kind of volume.  T2 instances aren't good for much, in my experience.  Can you specify where the data is coming from?

Comment: The data is coming from Coinbase pro/GDAX from the full order-book level channel, so every order that gets sent to the exchange should be recorded I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It depends on the WebSocket server.**

If your first script cannot run fast enough to match the message generation speed on server side, the TCP receive buffer will become full and the server will slow down on sending packets. Assuming a near-constant message production rate, unprocessed messages will pile up on the server, and the server could be coded to let them accumulate or eventually drop them.

Even if the server never dropped a message, without enough computational power, your instance would never catch up - on 8/15 it could be dealing with messages from 8/10 - so instance upgrade is needed.

**Does data rate vary greatly throughout the day** (e.g. much more messages in evening rush around 20:00)? If so, data loss may have occurred during that period.

But is Python really that slow? 5GB/day is less than 100KB per second, and even a fraction of one modern CPU core can easily handle it. Perhaps you should stress test your scripts and optimize them (reduce small disk writes, etc.)